# Execute a command in multiple directories with variable parameters bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have multiple folders each one include the following

- a video file `xFilename.mp4`
- a folder named `Subs`, which include many srt files `xFilename.srt`.

How can I use `bash` to execute an `mkvmerge` command for each folder to merge each mp4 file with all the srt files in its `Subs` folder and output an mkv file with the same name as the mp4 file.

Something like

```bsh
for dir in ./* :
   if (there is an mp4 file) :
       name = "mp4 file name without the extension, dunno how to do that"
       mkvmerge -o ./"$dir"/"$name".mkv ./"$dir"/"$name".mp4 "$dir"/Subs/*.srt
```

How to write that in the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying your pseudo-code:

```bsh
for mp4file in */*.mp4; do
    [ ! -f "$mp4file" ] && continue
    mkvmerge -o "${mp4file%.mp4}.mkv" "$mp4file" "${mp4file%/*}/Subs"/*.srt
done
```

What's happening here is that I iterate over all MP4 files found in any subdirectory of the current directory, and for each found file I execute that `mkvmerge` command.

The test, `[ ! -f "$mp4file" ]`, is there to catch the case where no files matches the given pattern.  If the condition is true (the variable contains a name that does not refer to an existing regular file or symbolic link to a regular file), then this iteration is skipped using `continue`.

The expansion `${variable%pattern}` will remove the shortest substring matching `pattern` from the end of the value of the variable `variable`.  This means that given that `mp4file` contains the pathname of some MP4 file, then

- `${mp4file%.mp4}.mkv` removes the `.mp4` from the end of the pathname in `mp4file`, and adds `.mkv`.
- `${mp4file%/*}/Subs` removes the filename portion of the pathname, as well as the last `/`, in `mp4file` and adds `/Subs` to the end of it.